# Hard Auction Game Theory Question: Optimal Strategy with Asymmetric Info

Tags: game-theory, auction-theory

There is a box containing $X$ dollars. $X$ is a random variable which is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1000$.

The box is auctioned via a first price sealed bid auction. There are two participants in the auction. Player 1 only knows that $X$ is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1000$, whereas player 2 also knows whether $X$ is greater than or less than $500$ dollars.

To clarify, $X$ and the values of the bids can be arbitrary real numbers; they do not have to be integers.

*What is the optimal strategy for player 1?*

I've been hitting my head against this problem for a few days, but I haven't gotten much further than that one would *probably* want to play a random strategy where you bet a dollars y% of the time and b dollars z% of the time.

But what would the optimal values for a,b,y,z be?

Comment: so for a given round, $$ $$ if your bet is higher, you give up your bet and take what's in the box $$ $$ if his bet is higher, you net nothing $$ $$ correct?

Comment: Correct. Sorry, I should have made that clear.

Comment: It's not clear exactly how the bidding is conducted.  From your final comment, I gather that each player submits a *single* sealed bid which the other one cannot see until both bids are unsealed. The person submitting the higher of the two bids then receives the contents of the box in exchange for the amount bid.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's accurate. Sorry, I know there's a lot of moving parts here. Traditional, standard single sealed bid auction.

Comment: is your opponent using a similar $a_{\pm},b_{\pm},y_{\pm},z_{\pm}$ strategy and does he know that we/you know that he knows plus vs minus ... guessing that if he knew that you knew he knew, his strategy would be different than if he thought you did not know he knew

Comment: @TeenPhilosopher I'm confused how the opponent has extra information if what is whispered is chosen completely randomly... Is what is whispered true rather than completely random?

Comment: @mathworker21 The information whispered is whether there is more OR less than $500 in the box. The answer to that can change depending on the particular round/instance/auction, and both possible answers occur with probability 0.5.

Comment: @TeenPhilosopher Ughh, why does nobody read what I write on this website. Here is, once again, my question: Is what is whispered the truth or not?

Comment: @mathworker21 Indeed, it is.

Comment: @TeenPhilosopher then you should rewrite the question. as of now, it is flat out misleading. Also, isn't the optimal strategy for playing once the same as the optimal strategy for playing an arbitrarily large number of times?

Comment: 1. Is the amount of money integer (or a decimal number with $2$ places after decimal point), or an arbitrary real number? Also, can you bet integer or arbitrary real number? 2. What happens if you two bet the same? 3. What happens if there is exactly $500$ in the box, what does the whisperer say? 4. And most importantly, do you know how to solve the case with no whisperer (you have the same information as opponent)? If you know, could you give a sketch of proof within your question? It would be helpful for person giving an answer to this to see how you think about it and what notation you use.

Comment: @prosinac - I have exactly the same questions, thanks for asking them!  :)  Re: the symmetric case, I think it has a Nash equilibrium of each player bidding $499$ if (1) the bids must be integers and (2) a coin flip decides the winner in case of tied bids.  I think each player bidding $500$ is also another Nash equilibrium.  But I'm not sure about either, and in fact there might be more...?

Comment: What happens if both bids are the same? Does each player pay half the amount bid and receive $\frac{X}2$ dollars?

Answer (score 0):

So the grounding assumption here is that both players are only trying to maximise their own profit, and both players will avoid strategies that do not pursue this goal. Essentially both players want the largest positive EV (Expected value, or expected gain from the bid). We will also be talking about the average outcome of the bet, or the outcome of an arbitrarily large number of bets.

We quickly note that in the symmetric case with no additional information, both players will bid $499$, because the average value of the box is $500$. We reach $499$ as this is the first and only stable equilibrium for both players. i.e. $499$ beats all bets from $0-498$ with a payoff of 1, draws with itself at 0.5, and loses only to illogical bets with a zero or negative EV. Visualising how this equilibrium stabilises is easier if you consider the same question but with the option to place subsequent bids. If the first player bids 1, the other will bid 2, the first will bid 3, ...

The EV for both players is ~$0.5$ or $0$, depending on what happens in the tiebreak. It is debatable perhaps that the best bid is $500$, but since the game is not competitive and players are only looking to maximise their money, no player will choose a bid with an EV of $0$.

The important conclusion is that crucially, without additional information, any bet above $500$ has a negative EV.

The asymmetric case is clearer to understand from the perspective of player 2 (who has more information).

Player 2 knows that the box is either in the range $[0,500]$ or $[500,1000]$. We shall call the $[0,500]$ case $L$ and the second $[500,1000]$, $H$. Clearly for $L$ the average value of the box is $250$ and for $H$ it is $750$. Thus, player 2 will never bid more than $249$ and $749$ respectively. And indeed, player 2 will bid $249$ for $L$.

However player 2 is also logical and understands that any bet from player 1 above $499$ is illogical, since player 1 has no information on the state ($L$ or $H$). Thus, player 2 is guaranteed to win with a bid of $500$. Player 2's overall EV is $0.5$ for L and $250$ for H.

Player 1's best strategy is to bid $249$ always. Any bid larger than $249$ but smaller than $500$ can only beat player 2 in the situation $L$, and in that case player 1 has a negative EV.

As the game is not competitive, player 1 should never bid more than $499$. This is because, from player 1's perspective, we have a $50\%$ chance to be in $L$ and a $50\%$ chance to be in $H$. If we are in $L$, then player 1 loses $250-B$, where $B$ is the bid. If we are in $H$, player 1 gains $750-B$. The EV is $\frac{500-B}{2}$ for a bid of $B$. Since both $L$ and $H$ are equally likely, the only values of $B$ which return a positive EV here are 250-499. But, player 1 is aware that player 2 is able to deduce all of this, and thus player 2 will never lose $H$ to a bet under $500$. Thus, to win in $H$, player 1 is forced to bid more than $500$, but this returns a negative EV, which contradicts player 1's goal to only maximise their own money.

Even if the game was competitive, nothing actually changes. Player 1 cannot hope to beat player 2 with any strategy. Betting less than $250$ is illogical since player 2 will always in the boxes. Always betting 250 still loses to a 250,500 strategy in the long term. Always/ sometimes betting exactly 500 gives a negative EV for player 1 in $L$ and still allows player 2 to get a positive EV in $H$ with larger bets. Any strategy involving bids of more than $500$ from player 1 automatically have a negative EV for reasons previously discussed.

Comment: To be precise, you're saying P1 should bid $249$ and P2 should bid $249$ (if L) or $500$ (if H), right?  This is a nice start, but it is not a Nash equilibrium, even among deterministic strategies.  E.g. if P2 were to bid $249$ (if L) and $250$ (if H), P2's EV would be much higher.

Comment: $500$ is necessary as a minimum bid since P1 can use the same strategy as the symmetric game as I explained and always bid $499$. This gives P1 an EV of 0.5 again. Since both $499$ and $249$ have the same EV of 0.5, P1 should be indifferent to the decision and this justifies why P2 must bet $500$

Comment: P1's EV is a function of both players strategies.  You cannot simply say P1 bidding $499$ has an EV of $0.5$.  Against a P2 bidding $(249,500)$ when (L,H), a P1 bidding $499$ has a horrible negative EV.  Part (most?) of the difficulty of this problem comes from each player trying to outguess the other, a dynamic captured in the definition of Nash Equilibrium.  I don't know whether this game has a N.E. with deterministic strategies (and to be honest I'm guessing not).  I'm just pointing out that your solution is not a N.E.

Comment: @antkam I see, thanks for explaining! I clearly made a bad jump in logic when considering 499 vs 500 for P2.